# Why isn't pip v7.1.0 caching wheels?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm running pip v7.1.0 (latest as of this writing) and running into an issue where it's not caching at all.

Here is how I'm installing Django -

```
pip install --cache-dir=d:\pipcache django
```

The package installs successfully, but there is nothing cached. I've read the latest documentation and checked my `AppData/Local` path and it's empty. What I'm looking to do is have everything I install through pip cached, so all subsequent virtual environment creations are quick.

EDIT

Turns out that pip won't cache packages that have wheel files. I tried forcing pip to build the source `--no-binary=django` to no avail.

Having said that, how can I force pip to cache my requirements whether the maintainers have provided wheels or not?

Based on my understanding of pip, this should be the new default. Not sure why it isn't working, though.

Alternatively, I have to do this -

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir="D:/"-r reqs
pip install --no-index --find-links="D:/" -r reqs
```

Comment: Is `D:\pipcache` writeable?

Comment: @Alik It is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this within a venv? If so, you may have to explicitly install wheel into the venv using `pip install wheel`. After that, pip should start automatically building/caching your wheels.